# Google Place api key is not working for android application

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

I am trying to fetch the Place with the help of Place API Keys. Same API keys is working fine for MAP but it's not working for Place Picker.

Here is code flow what I am doing....

1. Enabled `Maps SDK for Android`
2. Enabled `Places API`

> Kye is restricted as mention into google document with the help of `applicationId` and `SHA1`.

Gradle file code `app.gradle`-

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

Now `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

These meta tag is inside `Application TAG`

Now here is my `Activity code`

```
btnLocation!!.setOnClickListener {
        val builder = PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), placePickerRequestCode)
        }catch (e : GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }catch (e : GooglePlayServicesRepairableException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

> Resultant function `onActivityResult`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == placePickerRequestCode) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data!!, this)
            lat = place.latLng!!.latitude
            long = place.latLng!!.longitude
            tvLocation!!.text = place.name
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR_RES_CODE $resultCode")
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR $data")
        }
    }
}
```

> Here I am getting always `ERROR_RES_CODE 2` and `ERROR null`

Please try to find the mistake what I am doing in that. I will be very thank full!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're not using the right dependency. As of 6 weeks ago, you would've wanted to use this one:

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'

But that version of the Places API has been deprecated. You should now be using this one:

> implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

Also, the PlacePicker is deprecated and will cease to work in June. So you really shouldn't even start using it:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

If you want something similar to the map portion of the PlacePicker, it's pretty easy to replicate that with a map and the Geocoder class. If you want place autocomplete, you'll need to use one of these samples and you'll need to pay Google its ransom because there's no longer a free way to do that:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos

Comment: This is not working for me! I have change the dependencies as per your suggestion.

Comment: Did you get rid of the PlacePicker? Because PlacePicker won't work at all in the new SDK.

Comment: Yes, I have same code in another project same dependencies, everything is same. But I don't know what mistake I am doing in that. I am searching on this from the morning. But did not get solution.

Comment: Try unrestricting the key in the Google API console?

Comment: Yes I tried this also try to replace the API Key, And my account is on billing. It's premium.

Comment: Just stick your key into the sample project: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos